# "initialiser element is not a compile-time constant" while creating GCD queue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

**MY BAD I WAS ACTUALLY WRITING THIS CODE OUTSIDE IMPLMENTATION, WHAT A BIG NAIVE MISTAKE**

I am learning GCD queues and creating blocks to run in background,

```
-(IBAction) refresh:(id) sender
{
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("app data", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        //. . . Call a method which download XML file from server . . .
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //. . . Update UI with dowanloaded data . . .    
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
}
```

but this line of code is showing compile error

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("eiap data", NULL);
```

**ERROR**: *initialiser element is not a compile-time constant*

---

I can say that something is wrong with "app data" a const char which I am creating kind a on the fly, But I don't know what is wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I am creating it kind a[sic] on the fly?"

Comment: I think there's something you're not showing us here.  Does your actual code declare `downloadQueue` static?

Comment: @robmayoff , your answer was spot on I was doing this outside implementation by mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I do this, it compiles:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("app data", NULL);
```

but if I do this, I get exactly the error you mention:

```
static dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("app data", NULL);
```

I think you're declaring it static.  Or you're actually declaring it outside the method body, as a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the spaces in your initializer string.

Use something like:

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.eiap.dataTask", NULL);
```

Apple recommends using the reverse DNS notation style strings.

[Here's a tutorial you can refer to, b.t.w.](http://volonbolon.net/post/749707585/grand-central-dispatch-queues) I hope my answer helps you out!

Comment: It was my mistake, I was writing this code outside implementation :(, now it's fixed

Comment: Do you know where these naming constraints (no spaces) come from?

Comment: [Here is Apple's reference for `dispatch_queue_create`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_queue_create) where they specify they recommend reverse DNS notation queue names.  Sounds like the compiler error was just a general operator error so all is well now :-) but I'd still recommend doing what Apple recommends for queue names.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                                           0);`

Here is my implementation of what you describe:

```
UIAlertView *av =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading Data" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
UIActivityIndicatorView *ActInd=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

[ActInd startAnimating];
[ActInd setFrame:CGRectMake(125, 60, 37, 37)];
[av addSubview:ActInd];
[av show];

dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
//dispatch_retain(callerQueue);
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                                       0);

dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    [self doLoadData];
    dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
        [av dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [av release];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
});
```

Comment: It was my mistake, I was writing this code outside implementation :(, now it's fixed